# Cannot get a consistent workaround for IE11 bug

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-11

I have a web app that I believe may be vulnerable to the following bug(s):

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/811930/ie11-crash-when-clearing-multiple-input-fields-with-jquery

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808033/ie11-two-reproducible-crashes-on-assigning-the-value-of-an-input-element-with-javascript

I'm attempting to create some sort of shim to work around this, but I have, thus far, been unsuccessful. Here is my attempted shim:

```
var oldVal = $.fn.val;

$.fn.val = function(value) {
    if (arguments.length) {
        var that = this;
        if (!value) {
            that = oldVal.call(this, ' ');
        }
        return oldVal.apply(that, arguments);
    }
    else {
        return oldVal.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

However, I'm not convinced that setting an empty string into the `input` element's value is the source of the crash. I'm looking for any information that might help create a workaround pending Microsoft's fix for the bug.

Comment: Try the solution from here: http://jsfiddle.net/dahjelle/zVjfY/ ('clearFormSetTimeout')

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure that empty string is the only thing that can cause a crash.

Comment: Did you try using the `setTimeout` method, though?

Comment: Meaning every use of jQuery's `val` function gets wrapped with a `setTimeout`?

Comment: Maybe.  Take a look at the code in the fiddle.  Also, I'm surprised your shim didn't work, that seems to be one of the accepted work-arounds.